# MailboxNotEnabledForRESTAPI error om Graph Api but works in Graph Explorer

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-graph-api, blazor-server-side

I use

```
Messages = await GraphServiceClient.Me.Messages.Request().GetAsync();
```

to get the E-mails from a user. But get the error:

```
MailboxNotEnabledForRESTAPI
```

MS page says the mailbox is not enabled. But that cannot be the case cause with the graph explorer i get the results. The api itself works, cause i can get user profile for example. Why does it work in explorer and not in my app?

thanks

UPDATE 04/24/21

I realized that the user is in 2 active directories. The one graph explorer is calling is the main one. The one not working is where the user in another active directory listed as an external user.

What do i need to do to get the emails from the user through the use of the other active directory?

Background:
In my App i want to use just one active directory. The users though are original registered through a number of different other active directories. Now i want to access the emails of the users through one active directory.

Comment: Which permissions did you set in AAD portal? Delegated or application permissions?

Comment: "Mail.ReadBasic", "Mail.Read","Mail.ReadWrite" in delegated. As far as i know app permissions are only nec. if no user is present.

Comment: where the given mailbox is located? is it Exchange online/M365 one?

Comment: Yes, in Office 365